# ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.NEW();

Tags: java, android

Estou com um problema com **ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.NEW();**

Não consigo entender porque não tenho acesso ao .NEW, simplesmente ele não existe, não acho e não encontro... preciso dele para criar a lógica de uma conversão de PDF para JPG... Alguém tem uma ideia de como acha-lo??? OBS: É para JAVA ANDROID.

```
    byte[] bytes;
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
    long length = file.length();
    bytes = new byte[(int) length];
    int offset = 0;
    int numRead = 0;
    while (offset < bytes.length
            && (numRead = is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length
            - offset)) >= 0) {
        offset += numRead;
    }

    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.NEW(bytes);
    String data = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    PDFFile pdf_file = new PDFFile(buffer);
    PDFPage page = pdf_file.getPage(1);
```

Encontrei este exemplo no Google, mas não lembro onde (Perdi o link)...

Comment: Não encontro nenhum método `NEW` na [documentação](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html), aliás é estranho um método com nome capitalizado (em Java, normalmente só se usa tudo em maiúsculas para denotar constantes). De onde você conhece esse método, tem alguma referência que pode indicar? De todo modo, veja se o método `allocate` ou `allocateDirect` não servem pra você, ou talvez o `wrap` se você já possui um array de bytes e quer criar um buffer a partir dele.

Comment: Olá amigo! Editei a minha pergunta com o código que tenho dúvida, é para pegar uma pagina de um PDF e converter para JPG

Comment: Nesse caso, muito provavelmente o que você quer é o `wrap`. Talvez o `NEW` se refira a alguma versão bastante antiga da API, não sei... Experimente: `ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);`

Comment: Ok, irei fazer os teste e passo o retorno!